# express connect-redis not working

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to use express session 'connect-redis' for first time. Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ store: new RedisStore, secret: 'lolcat' }));
app.get('/logging', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.logged) {
        res.send('Welcome back!');
    } else {
        req.session.logged = true;
        res.send('Welcome!');
    }
});
app.listen(8888);
```

When I try to start the server through command line, it shows error:

```
RadisStore.prototype._proto_= Store.prototype;
TypeError: Cannor read property 'prototype' of undefined;
```

That is 'Store' is undefined. What is the wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the parenthesis:

```
app.use(express.session({ store: new RedisStore(), secret: 'lolcat' }));
```

First. But secondly, you need to add options (https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis):

```
app.use(session({ store: new RedisStore({
  client: An existing redis client object you normally get from redis.createClient(),
  host: Redis server hostname,
  port: Redis server portno,
  ttl: Redis session TTL in seconds,
  db: Database index to use,
  pass: Password for Redis authentication,
  prefix: Key prefix defaulting to "sess:",
  url: String that contains connection information in a single url (redis://user:pass@host:port/db),
}), secret: 'keyboard cat' }))
```

Comment: Still not working. I'm following the tutorial:
http://www.hacksparrow.com/use-redisstore-instead-of-memorystore-express-js-in-production.html

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but I solved the problem:
`Due to express 4.x.x changes, we now need to pass express-session to the function connect-redis exports in order to extend express-session.Store:

var session = require('express-session') , RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({ store: new RedisStore(options), secret: 'keyboard cat' }))`